# What causes the strange lines in Chrome on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

From time to time I get strange colorful lines on my screen in Chrome. It only effects certain websites. I tried disabling "Hardware acceleration" in the settings but that didn't seem to help. What is the cause?

Here is a Facebook screen
[image]

And a Stackexchange screen. Note it only affects the top bar.

[image]

Comment: Resetting Pram resolved it, but I still want to know the cause as it happens every once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

If it was only happening in Chrome, I would have suggested uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome. I would have also suggested that you use Safari and see if you get the same issues.

Not sure how the PRAM would affect this 1 program and not others. If you set any kinds of [flags in Chrome](http://chrome://flags/)(link works in chrome only) then I would hit the `Reset All` on the flags page and restart the browser.

Comment: It might be related to how Chrome uses the GPU.